# Each time the counter hits 6 - A basic math issue help

Tags: php, math

Using a php like so..

```
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) ...
```

I have this html element that is rendered several times. I want to, each time we arrive at the sixth element, it adds a "style:margin-right: 0px;" for example.

My question is:
How can we find always the 6th element ?

Update: So that can mark the 6th element, then the 12th element, then the 18th element then the 24th and, at least, the 30th.

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Comment: It's a good practice to do achieve this in Javascript than in PHP .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator, `%`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
  if ($i % 6 == 5) {
    # Add what you want---I don't use PHP much
  }
}
```

The modulo operator, `%`, divides the left hand side by the right hand side, and then reports the *remainder* of the result.  So, for instance, `15 % 6 == 3`, because `15 == 6*2 + 3`.  In the expression `a % b == c`, `c` will range from `0` to `b-1`.  If you had `$i % 6 == 0` in the above test, it would style the first element, the seventh element, etc.; this way, it'll style the sixth element, the twelfth element, etc.  This is because when you're on the sixth element, `$i == 5`, and `5 % 6` is of course `6`.  For more information, check out [what Wikipedia has to say about the modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will need to understand and study why does 6==5 also works. Oh well... I've marked your post as useful because indeed it is. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This will also avoid the need for a check on the first case. Wow. :)

Comment: It's not that `6 == 5`, it's `$i % 6 == 5`, which parses as `($i % 6) == 5`, just like `$i * 3 == 2` is `($i * 3) == 2` instead of `$i * (3 == 2)`.  As for why you want to check when `$i % 6 == 5` (instead of `== 0`), it's because you're counting starting at `0`, not at `1`.  The modulo operator will return the sequence `0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,...` for increasing `$i`, as should make sense; if you start at `$i = 0`, then the sixth value `$i` takes is `5`, and `5 % 6 == 5` because `5 == 6*0 + 5`.  If you started at `$i = 1`, you'd want to check `$i % 6 == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the mod of $i and 6 is 0 (means that $i is evenly divisible by 6).

```
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
   if($i % 6 == 0) {
      // this is a sixth element
   }
   ...
}
```

If you don't want this to happen on the first iteration ($i == 0), you'll also need to add that check to the if statement:

```
if($i > 0 && $i % 6 == 0){ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using modulus (%)

```
if(!($i % 6)) { 
    // add style
}
```

or

```
if(($i % 6) == 0) {
    // add style
}
```

EDIT: Kaleb beats me to it =/